# Create new variable in R that is determined by whether or not other variables are missing

Tags: r

I run experiments that have multiple versions of the same question, depending on the condition to which the participant is assigned. So, suppose I have 2 conditions: A and B. In my data file, the response values to each question show up in different columns

[image: screenshot].

I would like to accomplish 2 things:

1. Create a variable called "Condition" that assigns value "A" if, e.g., the value for Q1ifCondA is not blank, and similarly assigns value "B" if Q1ifCondB is not blank.
2. Create single variables for each question, Q1, Q2, and Q3 that assigns the value from Q1ifCondA to Q1 if Condition==A and from Q1ifCondB to Q1 if Condition==B.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group similar question columns in a loop (`lapply`) by using `grep` to find the position of individual question column names ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3') and subset the dataset (`df1[grep(x, names(df1))]`).  From the example data, it is not clear whether there will be cases with both columns 'non-blank' or both 'blank' and also not mentioned about how to deal with such cases.  Assuming that it doesn't occur, we can use `max.col` to get the column position (which will give either 1 or 2).  Replace that index with 'A' or 'B' (`LETTERS[1:2][max.col...]`)

```
 df1[paste0('ConditionQ', 1:3)] <- lapply(paste0('Q',1:3), function(x)
              {x1 <- df1[grep(x, names(df1))]
              LETTERS[1:2][max.col(x1!='')]})

 df1
 #   Partic Q1ifCondA Q2ifCndA Q3ifCondA Q1ifCondB Q2ifCondB Q3ifcondB ConditionQ1
 #1      1         3        6         8                                         A
 #2      2         1        5         4                                         A
 #3      3                                      7         4         2           B
 #4      4         1        9         6                                         A
 #5      5                                      5         9         4           B
 #6      6                                      4         8         5           B
 #7      7         6        3         3                                         A
 #8      8                                      7         4         7           B
 #    ConditionQ2 ConditionQ3
 #1           A           A
 #2           A           A
 #3           B           B
 #4           A           A
 #5           B           B
 #6           B           B
 #7           A           A
 #8           B           B
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Partic = 1:8, Q1ifCondA = c("3", "1", "", "1", 
"", "", "6", ""), Q2ifCndA = c("6", "5", "", "9", "", "", "3", 
""), Q3ifCondA = c("8", "4", "", "6", "", "", "3", ""), Q1ifCondB = c("", 
"", "7", "", "5", "4", "", "7"), Q2ifCondB = c("", "", "4", "", 
"9", "8", "", "4"), Q3ifcondB = c("", "", "2", "", "4", "5", 
"", "7")), .Names = c("Partic", "Q1ifCondA", "Q2ifCndA", "Q3ifCondA", 
"Q1ifCondB", "Q2ifCondB", "Q3ifcondB"), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = "data.frame")
```